# django-wysiwyg-redactor's RedactorField

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-wysiwyg-redactor and I have two question

1. How can I send RedactorField input to the template as a field in the form?
2. I'm using django-modeltranslation as well, but in admin site other language fileds for redactor input is ordinary
       TextField.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbeFQ.png) How can I fix this?

I believe that there should be some easy ways for my problems. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this FAQ https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/how-to-install/.

To install Redactor, place the following code between the `<head></head>` tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/redactor/redactor.css" />
<script src="/js/redactor/redactor.js"></script>
```

If your Redactor download is placed in a different folder, don't forget to change file's paths.

You can call Redactor using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('#content').redactor();
});
</script>
```